# External hard drive's data+ and data- cables shorted and hard drive is showing unallocated

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

When I was trying to connect my external SSD to my computer, the usb socket accidentaly shorted while PC was reading data inside and connection to SSD instantly lost. Now when I fix the short circuit and connect it again, it shows the disk unallocated like below image:

[image]

I tried recovering partition with EaseUS Partition Master program but it's taking longer than usual (1 hour elapsed):

[image]

Should I wait EaseUS to finish scanning or should I do something else? There was highly important files inside this external SSD. I need to recover them.

Comment: [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Comment: Let this be a lesson that backups are a necessity.

Comment: @gronostaj Maybe you won't believe but I was connected this SSD to take a backup of it.

Comment: A SSD does not have or use a *"disk"*, and is not a *"hard"* drive.

Answer (score 1):

No problem, I removed the SSD from external hard drive box and plugged in with a SATA to USB adapter and SSD is still working. It looks like only external hard drive box is broken.